# Is their any need merchant account for In app purchase in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to use In app purchase in android. I have a developer account for android play store. But I just want to ask is their any necessary of merchant account details to **test** android In app purchase functionality.

If no then please guide me how I can test In App using test account.

Answer (score 0):

You will not see an option to create and manage In App products for your app until you have setup your Merchant Account. Due to this, you must have one to test and deploy apps using in app purchases.

Comment: So, you mean - Unlike iOS In-App purchase provided by Apple I will need to add valid credit card credentials to set up my Google In-App Merchant account and its free (not like in iOS iTunes - they charge yearly for around $99 price)?
Right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting up a Merchant Account is completely free of charge.